# context.startActivity() does not start activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am currently working on an alarm clock, which should start an activity after a certain time has passed. For this, I am using a PendingIntent with a BroadcastReceiver like shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void btnAlarmSetWakeup(View view) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, WakeupAlarmActivity.class);
        alarmIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        context.startActivity(alarmIntent);
    }
}
```

```
public class WakeupAlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wakeup_alarm);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {

            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
            KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(this.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
        }
        else {

            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, after 3 seconds the AlarmReceiver class gets executed, but it doesn't start the WakeupAlarmReceiver activity.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You cannot launch an activity from the background on modern versions of Android. Please use a "heads-up" notification instead.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do other alarm clock apps do it then? Do they have kind of escalated permissions? And since what version is this mandatory?

Comment: "How do other alarm clock apps do it then?"-- the only alarm clock apps that I use alert users via heads-up notifications. If the phone is idle (e.g., screen is locked), your activity appears. If the phone might be in use, a notification is shown instead. This ensures that the background app only takes over the screen at points in time that are safe. Restrictions on background activity starts [were introduced in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts); using heads-up notifications was a good idea before that.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you very much! You saved me from a lot of pain.